# Where to call becomeFirstResponder(), at ViewDidAppear or ViewWillAppear?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, first-responder

**What I want**:

A `textField` and a `textLabel` is included in the `tableView`. When the **tableView** is present the `textField` will be the `firstResponder` and brings out the keyboard.

**Problems I have:**

the App is only shows the keyboard if the `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` is called within `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad`  (`textField` and `textLabel` is not showing at all).

**How I fixed it:**

The bug is not reproducible when I moved the `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` call into `viewDidAppear`

**Question:**

Am I spouse to call `becomeFirstResponder()` function inside the `viewDidAppear` function? otherwise the keyboard will block all the other views

*Many Thanks*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Think about what `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, and `viewDidAppear` *mean*.

- `viewDidLoad` means that the view controller *has* a view — but that view is not yet part of the interface.
- `viewWillAppear` means that the view controller's view will become part of the interface — but hasn't yet.
- `viewDidAppear` means that the view controller's view *did* become part of the interface.

You need your view to be part of the interface before your text field can summon the keyboard. Only then is the table view actually *showing and configured*. In other words, at this point the interface has settled down into its actual form, and we are ready to place the keyboard correctly above it.

Comment: you'd be more accurate saying added to the window rather than become part of interface.

Comment: @malhal Those seem to me to be two ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: Ok it might help that viewWillAppear means the UIView received viewWillMoveToWindow. i.e. the window property is now valid.